# PHP curl doesn't work on page that contain Ajax Script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

There is a table in a web page with two filters :
1. Period
2. Segment
When user submit the form, data will display in table.

I need to fetch the data with curl. But I have a problem. When I try to view source, I think the data processed with Ajax. Here is the code (from view source) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow( obj1, lvl, kws, wtl, kndt, cmdf, csss ) {
        $.ajaxSetup ({  
            cache: false  
        });

          $.ajax({
              url : "wbs/api_pagename.php?lvl=" + ( parseInt( lvl ) + 1 ) + "&kws=" + kws + "&wtl=" + wtl + "&dtl=" + kndt + "&periode=" + g_periode + "&segmen=" + g_segmen,
              dataType: 'json',
              beforeSend:function(){
                  progshow();
              },
              success:function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ){
                  var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl_1');
                  temprow = document.getElementById( obj1 ).rowIndex;
                  lvl++;

                  for ( var i in data ){
                      temprow++;
                      var mainRow = tbl.insertRow( temprow );
                      var trId = obj1 + "_" + i;
                      mainRow.id = trId;

                      if (csss.length > 0) {
                          csss += ' ';
                      }

                      csss += "css_" + obj1;
                      mainRow.className = csss;

                      var newCell = mainRow.insertCell( 0 );
                      newCell.innerHTML = '';

                      var newCell = mainRow.insertCell( 1 );
                      newCell.innerHTML = '';

                      for ( _i = 1; _i < lvl - 1; _i++ ) {
                          newCell.innerHTML += '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                      }

                      if (lvl <= 2) {
                          newCell.innerHTML += "<a href=\"javascript:doMenu('" + trId + "','" + lvl + "','" + data[i][0] + "','" + data[i][1] + "','" + data[i][2] + "','','" + csss + "');\" id='a" + trId + "'>[+]";
                      }

                      newCell.innerHTML += data[i][ 2 + parseInt( lvl ) ];
                      addrow1( mainRow, data, i, 1 );
                  }

                  proghide();
              },
              error : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                  alert(jqXHR.status);
                  alert(textStatus);
                  alert(errorThrown);
              }
          });
    }
</script>
```

I tried to fetch the data with PHP curl, but I failed.
 Here is my PHP Code :

```
<?php
    $kipas1 = "entered_user=XXXXX&entered_password=XYZXYZ&login=login&redirect_to=wp-admin/";
    $cr = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_URL, "http://webpage.com/index.php" );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3000 );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/7.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 5.1)" );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $kipas1 );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'C:\xampp\htdocs\coc\cookie.txt' );

    $whoCares = curl_exec( $cr ); 

    $myvars = "lvl=2&kws=ALL&wtl=ALL&dtl=ALL&periode=201511&segmen=ALL";
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_URL, "http://webpage.com/target.php" );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

    $result = curl_exec( $cr );

    echo $result;
?>
```

The result is only show the select element (dropdown list) with my variable selected, but the table is not showing. I don't know why. Maybe it's because the ajax or something.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You have to curl for `wbs/api_pagename.php` the same way as ajax does to fetch data from there.

Comment: Check for errors `error_reporting(E_ALL);  `

Comment: Okay. I will try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code shows that an AJAX call is being made to wbs/api_pagename.php ( with a number of query string params).

If you want to access the data via cURL, your script will need to perform a HTTP GET request to this script. Judging from the source that you posted, this script will return JSON data.